# In RxJS, does Observer get injected into Observable execution?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I have read through the [ReactiveX](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) documentation several times, and still cannot wrap my head around exactly what happens when an *Observer* subscribes to an *Observable*.

Let's look at a simple example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 

const observable = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.complete();
});

const observer = {
  next: (x) => console.log('got value ' + x),
  error: (err) => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('done')
};

observable.subscribe(observer);
```

[StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8tmaam).

---

**My Question:**

Where does the `subscriber` object that is passed to the *Observable* come from?

From the [RxJS documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable):

> It is not a coincidence that `observable.subscribe` and `subscribe` in 
>   `new Observable(function subscribe(subscriber) {...})` have the same name.
>   In the library, they are different, but for practical purposes you can
>   consider them conceptually equal.

So, apparently the object passed into the *subscribe* callback in the *Observable* constructor (`subscriber`) is **not** actually the `observer` object. At least not if you go by the quote above on how the library actually works.

If it is not the `observer` object that is passed in, then what exactly is `subscriber.next(1)` and `subscribe.complete()` calling? How does that connect to the `next` property in the `observer`?

---

**Clarifying Edit:**

I know how to utilize *RxJS* and indeed that one can *conceptually* imagine that the *Observer* is injected (as the quote says). However, I am here looking to understand how it *actually* works.

Comment: @ABOS Check the quote, that is not how it works in the library. Somewhat related, that is also not how *Promises* are built internally. The `reject` and `resolve` functions passed to the callback in the `Promise` constructor (the *executor function*) are not in fact coming from `then(onResolve, onReject)`. They come from the internal *Promise* implementation and when called they somehow execute the handlers in `then`, if attached. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @ABOS My question is how it actually works though. I believe in general that, by understanding how something works in-depth, you will be better at applying it. Adding clarifying edit to the OP.

Comment: Think of the subscriber as a wrapper around the observer that ensures `next`, `complete` and `errror` all exist and that any errors thrown from observer callbacks are caught and are routed appropriately. The subscriber is essentially an implementation detail: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2314

Comment: @cartant Thank you. Without subscribe, is it as if our observer was injected directly into the callback in the Observable constructor?

Comment: The call to the `subscribe` method calls the function passed to the `Observable` constructor. That function is stored internally as [`_subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.4.0/src/internal/Observable.ts#L37-L41) and it's called with the wrapped observer that's passed to the `subscribe` method [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.4.0/src/internal/Observable.ts#L210-L212) - note the `toSubscriber` call (just above it) that wraps the observer.

Comment: @cartant I went through all the relevant RxJS code (using a debugger and the source code), and posted an answer below explaining the process in brief. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Observable` creation process flows as follows:

An `Observable` is defined by the author (here manually with `new`, for purposes of the explanation):

```
const myObservable = new Observable(function subscribe(subscriber) {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.next(2);
  subscriber.complete();
  return function tearDownLogic() {
    console.log('runs when Observable for whatever reason is done (complete, error, or unsubscribed)')
  }
});
```

The `subscribe` callback passed to the `Observable` above is saved locally by the [Observable constructor](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/82482b2849ecaee9a22511ad9aa236d67b24dbe9/src/internal/Observable.ts#L37-L41):

```
constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic) {
  if (subscribe) {
    this._subscribe = subscribe;
  }
}
```

So, we have that entire `subscribe` function, defined by us or any other pre-made `Observable`, saved down for later execution.

An *Observer* can be passed to the `subscribe` callback in one of several forms. Either, as one to three functions directly (*next*, *error*, *complete*), or as an object with one or more of the same three methods. For purposes of this explanation, we will implement the last and more verbose option:

```
const observer = {
  next(v) {
    console.log(v);
  }
  error(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  complete() {
    console.log('Observable has now completed and can no longer emit values to observer');
  }
}
```

Now, the fun part starts. We pass the `observer` into the `Observable.subscribe(..)` method:

```
myObserver.subscribe(observer);
```

The [subscribe method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/82482b2849ecaee9a22511ad9aa236d67b24dbe9/src/internal/Observable.ts#L199-L226) looks like this:

```
  subscribe(observerOrNext?: PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void),
            error?: (error: any) => void,
            complete?: () => void): Subscription {


    const { operator } = this;
    const sink = toSubscriber(observerOrNext, error, complete);


    if (operator) {
      sink.add(operator.call(sink, this.source));
    } else {
      sink.add(
        this.source || (config.useDeprecatedSynchronousErrorHandling && !sink.syncErrorThrowable) ?
        this._subscribe(sink) :
        this._trySubscribe(sink)
      );
    }


    if (config.useDeprecatedSynchronousErrorHandling) {
      if (sink.syncErrorThrowable) {
        sink.syncErrorThrowable = false;
        if (sink.syncErrorThrown) {
          throw sink.syncErrorValue;
        }
      }
    }


    return sink;
  }
```

Briefly described, the `subscribe` method:

1. Receives the `observer` in one of its previously discussed forms
2. `toSubscriber` converts the observer to a `Subscriber` object, regardless of its passed in form (the `Subscriber` instance is saved in the `sink` variable)
3. Note: The `operator` variable is `undefined`, unless you subscribe to an operator. Thus, just ignore the `if` statements around `operator`
4. `Subscriber` extends (is prototype-linked to) the `Subscription` object, which has two important methods on its prototype: `unsubscribe()`, `add()`
5. `add(..)` is used to add "*tear down logic*" (functions) to the `Observable`, that will run when an `Observable` *completes* or is *unsubscribed*. It will take any function that is passed to it, wrap it in a `Subscription` object, and place the function into the `Subscription`'s `_unsubscribe` variable. This `Subscription` is saved on the `Subscriber` we created above, in a variable called `_subscriptions`. As noted, we do all that so that when the `Subscriber` is *unsubscribed* or *completes*, all the `add()`'ed *tear down logic* executes
6. As a side note, `Observable.subscribe()` returns the `Subscriber` instance. Thus, you can call `mySubscriber.add( // some tear down logic)` on it at any point to add functions that will execute when the `Observable` *completes* or is *unsubscribed*
7. An important part now enfolds: `this._trySubscribe(sink)` runs (inside `add()`, as a parameter). `_trySubscribe(..)` is the function that actually runs the `subscribe` callback earlier saved by the `Observable` constructor. Importantly, it passes in `sink` (our new `Subscriber` instance) as the callback to the `Observable` callback. In other words, when `subscriber.next(1)` inside the `Observable` executes, we are actually executing `next(1)` in the `sink` (`Subscriber`) instance (`next()` is on `Subscriber`'s prototype).

So, that takes me to the end, for now. There are more details inside `toSubscribe` and around the *unsubscribe* process, among other things, but those are outside the scope of this Q&A.

In short summary, to answer the question in the title, the *Observer* is indeed passed into the `Observable`, simply after being converted to a unifying `Subscriber` object.

Hopefully, that will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

No, an observer is not injected into an observable.

AFAICT, The confusion stems from the fact that the `new Observable(...)` syntax is more a low level factory than a useful pattern.

It is, more or less, the machinery that is used by more straightforward implementations like `of(value1, value2, ..., valueN)`, `from(enumeration)` and `fromEvent(...)`.

This methods are the actual use case you should concentrate upon.

Under the covers, all this methods bridge some sort of synchronous or asynchronous value or interaction *into* the wonderful world of observable streams. To do so they, in some way or another, act *like* a proper Observer: they generate items and put them into the stream. To do so, they use a function that is called `next`. Just like the method in the `Observer` implementations, bacause actually is called exactly in the same way.

In particular, you can look at the implementation of the subscribe method here:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts

If you want to learn what actually happens during subscribe, I suggest you to actually look at the code.
But, IMO, you should try only after having familiarized with the various Observable creation functions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know how to use RxJS and indeed how it works in a non-technical sense. That is not what I am trying to get at here. I am implementing the low-level *Observable* constructor to demonstrate my question, which is: How does this process actually work in the library. According to the quote (see OP and the spec), we *can* for the sake of simplicity assume that it is indeed injected, but as it says: that is *not* how the library actually works.

Comment: Well, then you should read the code linked in the answer. But be prepared to enter a pretty long journey. You cannot really understand the implementation details of the code without reading it. Swallow that blue pill!

Comment: Hehe ugh, you are probably right. Which pill, which pill. Down the rabbit hole we go... :)

Comment: Now done and posted below. I went through every line of code, to make sure I understood it fully. Thanks for the pointer.